# How to write name of array you need in function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write in input field the name of array (a, b or other array I chosen). How to write name of array you need in function? inputs[3].value? It is not work. How do this? I have 4 fields. The fourth field would be better select options.

Comment: `a` and `b` are variable names, not the "name of the array". What if I do `var c = a;`? Does the array have two names now? Why do want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @imtheman my bad sorry.

Comment: `inputs[0].value = a[0][0];` should get you the first one.  I'm not seeing where you reference `a` or `b`, and if you do reference them for your table script, `a` and `b` should be defined before filling the table.

Comment: a and b - it is example. User should write in field name of the array(of course would be better that user choose select options).

Comment: but the code you have given us should be solving a problem you have.  If it doesn't make sense, it's hard to help you.  give us an example of how you are building `data`

Comment: This doesn't look like proper javascript. Why is it not in a script section? What is `data`? How is array a and b being used?

Comment: @Cat, Hi, I may have a solution its a bit tricky, but maybe it will give you a direction, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/qnea6bed/

Comment: You don't understand me. I want to user, who went in my page shoud write in this field name of the array which he need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array of arrays instead. Or better yet, an object:

```
var arrays = {
  a : [
    ["Name1",4,"x",5,4,5,4,5],
    ["Name2","x",2,"x",4,4,3,4],
    ["Name3",5,4,"x",3,3,4,4],
    ["Name4",4,2,3,4,"x",3,4],
    ["Name5","x","x",3,4,"x","x","x"]
  ],
  b : [
    ["Name1",4,"x",5,4,5,4,5],
    ["Name2","x",2,"x",4,4,3,4],
    ["Name3",5,4,"x",3,3,4,4],
    ["Name4",4,2,3,4,"x",3,4],
    ["Name5","x","x",3,4,"x","x","x"]
  ]
}
```

You can then use them like this:

```
arrays.a
```

or this:

```
arrays['a']
```

It is this second form that allows you to pass the name of which array you want to use:

Comment: How to will view my full code with this changes. Please introduce me full code, which work.